# JAXB: Create attribute for inner element

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, attributes

I need to create XML file with following structure:

```
<Persons>
   <Person ID="1">
      <Name></Name>
      ...
   </Person>
   <Person ID="2">
      <Name></Name>
      ...
   </Person>
   ...
</Persons>
```

I have already tried all solutions on Stack Overflow, using `*@XmlPath("/Person/@ID")*`, `*@XmlAttribute(name="ID")*` in different ways and had no success. My code creates an attribute in root node or creates additional node before *Person* node. But attribute should be inside *Person* node

Method in Main.class:

```
public void savePersonDataToFile(File file) {
    try {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext
                .newInstance(PersonListXMLWrapper.class);
        Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        // Wrapping our person data.
        PersonListXMLWrapper wrapper = new PersonListXMLWrapper();
        wrapper.setPersons(personData);

        // Marshalling and saving XML to the file.
        m.marshal(wrapper, file);

        // Save the file path to the registry.
        setPersonFilePath(file);
    } catch (Exception e) { // catches ANY exception
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.setHeaderText("Cant save to file:\n" + file.getPath());
        alert.setContentText("Ooops, there was an error!");
    }
}
```

Person.class has variable declarations, methods for changing and getting them and constructor:

```
public class Person {
    private final IntegerProperty ID;
    private final StringProperty name;
    private final StringProperty surname;
    private final StringProperty prevSurname;
    private final StringProperty patronymic;
    ...
```

PersonListXMLWrapper.class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Persons")
public class PersonListXMLWrapper {

    private List<Person> persons;

    @XmlElement(name = "Person")
    public List<Person> getPersons() {
        return persons;
    }

    public void setPersons(List<Person> persons) {
        this.persons = persons;
    }


    @XmlPath("/Person/@IDAtt")
    public String IDAtt ="123";

    @XmlAttribute(name="ID")
    public String getID() {
        return IDAtt;
    }

    public void setID(String ID) {
        this.IDAtt = ID;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Did you try ElementWrapper like following        @XmlElementWrapper(name="persons")
   @XmlElement(name="person") 
   List<Person> person;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was extremely simple. I just had to add `*@XmlAttribute(name="ID")*` to method declaration in Person.class, instead of PersonListXMLWrapper.class:

```
public class Person {
    private final StringProperty ID;
    private final StringProperty name;
    private final StringProperty surname;
    private final StringProperty prevSurname;
    private final StringProperty patronymic;
    ...

    @XmlAttribute(name="ID")
    public String getID() {
        return ID.get();
    }
    public void setID(String ID) {
        this.ID.set(ID);
    }

    public StringProperty IDProperty() {
        return ID;
    }
```

So i get the following structure:

```
<Persons>
    <Person ID="1">
        <name>Name1</name>
        <surname></surname>
        <prevSurname></prevSurname>
        <patronymic></patronymic>
        ...
    </Person>
    <Person ID="2">
        <name>Name2</name>
        <surname></surname>
        <prevSurname></prevSurname>
        <patronymic></patronymic>
        ...
    </Person>
    ...
</Persons>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use another XML parser, I would recommend the Scilca XML Progression for writing a simple XML file (verifying it).

```
 import org.scilca.sxp.*; // The SXP package

 Node rootNode = new XMLNode("Persons");

 // First Persion
 Node p1 = Node.constructNode("<Person Id=\"1\"?");
 p1.add("Name").setValue("Jacob"); // Add a child element and set its value
 p1.add("Habit").setValue("Eating"); 

 rootNode.add(p1); // Add it to root node

 // Second Person
 Node p2 = Node.constructNode("<Person Id=\"2\">");
 p1.add("Name").setValue("Jacks");

 rootNode.add(p2);

 Document XmlDocument = new Document(rootNode);
 XmlWriter xw = XmlDocument.getWriter();
 xw.saveXml("D:/file.txt"); // text file to see if the file is correct
```

Comment: I have been googling it for half an hour but absolutely without any sense. Are you sure it is open-access?

Comment: Sorry! The creator deleted it from GitHub.